# changing font color with multiple .animate functions on multiple divs

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

So I am trying to change the font color of a div when you hover over a different element.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5QDYE/

I'm using two animate functions within the hover. One animate for the background div, the other for the text div. It looks something like this.

```
function () {
    $('#background').animate({
        height: "40px",
        width: "80px",
        marginTop: "0px",
        marginLeft: "0px"
    }, 500);
    $("#text").animate({ color: "#FFF" }, 500);
}, function () {
    $('#background').animate({
        height: "0px",
        width: "0px",
        marginTop: "20px",
        marginLeft: "40px"
    }, 500);
    $("#text").animate({ color: "#000" }, 500);
});
```

the background animation is working correctly, but the text will not change color.

Comment: You should load jQuery UI or a color plugin for animating colors.

Comment: BTW - If you are ready to give IE8-9 users up, you can do this entire thing with `CSS3 transition` instead of JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to use css3, try.

```
function () {
    $('#background').animate({
        height: "40px",
        width: "80px",
        marginTop: "0px",
        marginLeft: "0px"
    }, 500);
    $("#text").css({ 'color': "#FFF", 'transition' : 'color 1s' });
}, function () {
    $('#background').animate({
        height: "0px",
        width: "0px",
        marginTop: "20px",
        marginLeft: "40px"
    }, 500);
    $("#text").css({ 'color': "#000", 'transition' : 'color 1s' });
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ksRGc/)**

It seems like animation works in jquery ui lesser version i.e 1.9.1 and 1.9.2. but in 2.x it fails to do color animation, because it has been separated out in a [different color plugin package](http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.js).

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRTbc/)**

Comment: I really like your second solution. For some reason It works. even though its using jquery 2.x Thanks so much

Comment: @YeahMKD The reason why it works, You need to include color plugin a well. See the link in my answer.

Comment: Oh I see it now. I didn't notice it on the left side. Thanks